# puppet creating relationship between file, class and define

Tags: puppet

I want to create relationship between file, class and define.... Please check the below code....
The problem I am facing is, even if there is no change in deploy.cfg file, class and nexus::artifact always runs...

class and nexus::artifact should execute only if it detects a change in file

I know that we need to make use of subscribe and refreshonly=true. But I have no idea where to put this...

```
 file { 'deploy.cfg':
    ensure  => file,
    path    => '/home/deploy/deploy.cfg',
    mode    => '0644',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    content => "test",
    notify  => [Class['nexus'], Nexus::Artifact['nexus-artifact']],
    subscribe => File['/home/deploy/dir'],
  }

  class { 'nexus':
    url      => $url,
    username => $user,
    password => $password,
  }

  nexus::artifact { "nexus-artifact":
    gav        => $gav,
    packaging  => $packaging,
    output     => $targetfilepath,
    repository => $repository,
    owner      => $owner,
    mode       => $mode,
  }
```

**artifact.pp**

```
define nexus::artifact (
  $gav,
  $repository,
  $output,
  $packaging  = 'jar',
  $classifier = undef,
  $ensure     = update,
  $timeout    = undef,
  $owner      = undef,
  $group      = undef,
  $mode       = undef
) {
    include nexus
}
```

**init.pp**

```
class nexus (
  $url,
  $username = undef,
  $password = undef,
  $netrc = undef,
) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if there is no change in deploy.cfg file, class and nexus::artifact always runs

Well yes, *every* class and resource in your node's catalog is applied on every catalog run, unless a resource that is required to be applied before it fails.  That is normal.  The key thing to understand in this regard is that the first part of applying a catalog resource is determining whether the corresponding physical resource is already in sync; if it is, then applying the catalog resource has no further effect.

> class and nexus::artifact should execute only if it detects a change in file
>
> I know that we need to make use of subscribe and refreshonly=true.

Well, no.  You may be able to modulate the *effect* of applying that class and resource, but you cannot use the result of syncing another resource to modulate whether they are applied at all.  In any event, `refreshonly` is specific to `Exec` resources, and you don't have any of those in your code.

Comment: Could you give me an example to modulate class and resource ?