# puppet Exec always runs even if the subscribed create_resource doesn't run

Tags: puppet, foreman

I have attached report screenshot from foreman and pasted below is the class that I am having issue with.

If it's hard to go through the entire code, I am highlighting the `Exec` section that is not working as expected

```
exec { $service:
    path => ["/usr/bin/","/usr/sbin/","/bin"],
    subscribe  => Domain_ip_map[$domain_ip_map_titles],
    command => "sudo service nagios restart",   
}
```

The above `Exec[$service]` is subscribed to `Domain_ip_map[...]`, this in turn notified by `Exec['purge-config-files']` which `require => File['deployconfig.cfg']`.

Since there is no change in `deployconfig.cfg` file, `File['deployconfig.cfg']` doesn't run and hence no notify, so `Exec['purge-config-files']` and custom `Domain_ip_map` resource doesn't run. Up to this point everything working as expected. But the last part, `Exec[$service]` is subscribed to `Domain_ip_map`.

> When `Domain_ip_map` is not running, how can `Exec[$service]` execute
>   successfully ?

```
class testclass ( $data = {
        item1 => {
                domain      => 'testdomain.com',
                ipaddress   => '1.1.1.1',
        },
},
$baseconfigdir   = '/usr/local/servers',
$config_file_host = '/usr/local/test.cfg',
$config_file_service = '/usr/local/test_service.cfg' ) {

validate_hash($data)

$domain_ip_map_titles = keys($data)

file { "${baseconfigdir}": 
  ensure => directory,
}

exec { 'purge-config-files':
  command => "/bin/rm -f ${baseconfigdir}/*",
  notify => Domain_ip_map[$domain_ip_map_titles],
  require => File['deployconfig.cfg'],
  refreshonly => true,
}

file { 'deployconfig.cfg':
    ensure  => file,
    path    => '/home/deployconfig.cfg',
    mode    => '0644',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    content => "test",    
    notify  => Exec['purge-config-files'],
} 

#problem here, its subscribed to Domain_ip_map, but even if Domain_ip_map doesn't run, Exec['$service'] always execute, how???
exec { $service:
    path => ["/usr/bin/","/usr/sbin/","/bin"],
    subscribe  => Domain_ip_map[$domain_ip_map_titles],
    command => "sudo service nagios restart",   
}

create_resources(domain_ip_map, $data)
}

define domain_ip_map($domain, $ipaddress)  {
nagios_host { $domain:
  ....
}

nagios_service { "check_ping_${domain}":
  ....
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: You should be able to just change that subscribe to a require, or are you asking for something more?

Comment: Matt, I read the difference between require and subscribe, it differs only in refreshonly.. Could you give a real time example for this? like when to apply subscribe and require ?... I think I already tried that... I don't remember..anyway I am going to try require again

Comment: I just don't want Exec[$service] to be called when there is no Domain_ip_map run

Comment: Matt, I just tried require again, but its not working.... 

//Stage[main]/Nagios/Exec[nagios]/returns executed successfully

Comment: Oh, then you should edit the question to be clear that is what you are asking. You forgot the `refreshonly` on the `exec`.

Comment: Matt, refreshonly is the right answer, I am totally confused with foreman logs..
Pls post that as the answer, I will add more detail to that

Comment: I got some more info from 
https://ask.puppet.com/question/24908/track-changes-create_resources-pe-201532/

Comment: This seems to exhibit misconceptions very similar to those in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39899429/2402272).  Specifically, there is a big difference between `Domain_ip_map` *not applying any changes* and it *not running* (or it failing).